# Draw over image in a QLabel with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to draw over image with my mouse.
I simplified the problem by this code.
When i uncomment the line 31 the code doesn't work.
My goal is to draw over the image i want to select from my PC and save the image after modify it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(581, 463)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.selectImgeBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.selectImgeBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 121, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.selectImgeBtn.setFont(font)
        self.selectImgeBtn.setObjectName("selectImgeBtn")

        self.drawing = False
        self.brushSize = 2
        self.brushColor = QtCore.Qt.black
        self.lastPoint = QtCore.QPoint()

        self.imageLb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.imageLb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 10, 331, 201))
        self.imageLb.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.imageLb.setText("")
        self.imageLb.setObjectName("imageLb")
        self.imageLb.mousePressEvent = self.mousePressEvent
        self.imageLb.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent
        self.imageLb.mouseReleaseEvent = self.mouseReleaseEvent
        # self.imageLb.paintEvent = self.paintEvent # When i uncomment this line the program is broken

        self.selectImgeBtn.clicked.connect(self.setImage)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.selectImgeBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Image"))

    def setImage(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
        if fileName:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imageLb.width(), self.imageLb.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.imageLb.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.imageLb.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            print(self.lastPoint)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton) and self.drawing:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.imageLb)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.imageLb.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvasPainter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.imageLb, self.imageLb.rect())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* draw inside a widget outside of the `paintEvent()`. This is not supported by Qt.

You may draw on a `QImage` or `QPixmap` instead, and then in `paintEvent()` of your widget, draw that image. Images can be initialized with all pixels transparent as well, if you like to composite several images (background+drawing) instead of drawing on the background directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm new to PyQt5 this is my second day, so I don't understand exactly how to do it but I will try.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way is best for you is using QLabel to view the image and OpenCV to draw over the image by those events. The issue is you will need to refresh the image after each change. I did that in this project [project](https://github.com/zaher88abd/Segmenter), it is working, but it might be better to if you use QT library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your project is awesome.
I will use OpenCV for some tasks but now I'm trying to draw using QT library.